# Unable to load class 'javax.inject.Provider'

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

I am trying to use an API, but I got the Duplicate Classes error and I had to exclude some dependencies from it, but now I get this error, how can I solve it?

**This is my code**

```
implementation("pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3"){
    exclude("io.netty", "netty-codec")
    exclude("io.netty","netty-transport")
    exclude("io.netty","netty-buffer")
    exclude("io.netty", "netty-codec-http")
    exclude("io.netty", "netty-codec-socks")
    exclude("io.micronaut","micronaut-router")
    exclude("io.micronaut","micronaut-validation")
    exclude("io.micronaut","micronaut-context")
    exclude("io.micronaut","micronaut-runtime")
    exclude("io.micronaut","micronaut-websocket")
    exclude("io.micronaut","micronaut-http-netty")
    exclude("io.micronaut","micronaut-http-server-netty")
    exclude("io.micronaut","micronaut-http")
    exclude("io.micronaut","micronaut-http-client")
    exclude("io.micronaut","micronaut-core")
    exclude("io.micronaut","micronaut-inject")
    exclude("io.micronaut","micronaut-http-client-core")
    exclude("ch.qos.logback", "logback-classic")
    exclude("ch.qos.logback", "logback-core")
    exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-api")
    exclude("org.apache.commons", "commons-lang3")
    exclude("org.reactivestreams", "reactive-streams")
    exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-api")
    exclude("javax.annotation","javax.annotation-api")
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy{
            exclude("com.google.code.findbugs","jsr305")
            exclude("javax.inject","javax.inject")
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my error**

> **Unable to load class 'javax.inject.Provider'
> javax.inject.Provider**
> Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
> Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
> The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
> Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
> Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Comment: Removing the gradle package from your gradle cache should help:  rm -r gradle_package_path

Comment: Where can I find the gradle cache?